# Uploading single photo to 7 pages always fails 2 specific pages. OAuthException [code] => 2"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Uploading Photo to two of the pages I manage fails with `"unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later. OAuthException [code] => 2"`

I am using a batch request to upload. I am a manager of all 7 pages. Debugging the Access Token gives me:

```
Issued  1385854349 (on Saturday)
Expires Never
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  create_note, manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, user_groups, video_upload
```

I can post a link from the batch request to all 7 pages with no error. When I change the code to post a photo, only 2 of the pages fail. The other 5 pages post the single photo correctly. Further I tried to use the AlbumID instead of the PageID with the same results. 5 pass 2 fail. I also tried to post to each individually with the same result. The 2 pages always fail regardless. Any ideas? I can post the code but I am not sure that will help as this seems to be server side.

```
`$queries = array(
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/accounts?limit=50'),
    );

    try{
            $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
    }catch(Exception $o) {
            error_log($o);
    }

    $user_info  = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
    $pages   = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);

                     - Then later -
```

`

```
`                      `foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {

                         foreach($accounts['data'] as $account){
                            if($account['id'] == $id){
                            //echo $id;
                            $ACCESS_TOKEN = $account['access_token'];
                            echo "<p>Page Access Token: $ACCESS_TOKEN</p>";
                         }  
                    }

            //echo $id;
                            $batchPost[] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => "/$id/photos?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN" , 'body' => http_build_query($body));`
```

Comment: How did you get the access token? Did you call /me/accounts on the graph API?

Comment: Yes i do. I pasted the code above. Then I get the ACCESS tokens and apply them based on the pageID. Then submit the batch.

Comment: I figured it out. This behavior is a reported bug when setting Country or Age group in the Page settings. I removed the Country tag from the setting and it is working fine!